# Groovy - Delegate DefaultGroovyMethods methods to generic object

Tags: generics, groovy, delegates, default

I have a generic class that encapsulates objects of various types.  Because I'm using generics I can't use the @delegate annotation (since it doesn't work with generics, def, or Object types).  Instead I'm taking advantage of the methodMissing and propertyMissing methods to pass on method calls and property access to the encapsulated object.  The problem I've run into though is how to delegate calls to methods added by DefaultGroovyMethods (each, collect, unique, etc.).  I've tried to do the following:

```
protected void setObject(T object)
{
  // Save the object
  this.object = object

  // Delegate all the default Groovy methods to the object
  DefaultGroovyMethods.class.methods*.name.unique().each({ name ->
    this.metaClass.'static'."${name}" = this.object.&"${name}"
  })
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work at all.  Is it even possible to override default Groovy methods via the meta class?  If it is, then what needs to be changed to make it work?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it's what you want, but you mean like this?

```
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
class Wrapper<T> {
    T wrapped

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        if(wrapped.respondsTo(name)) {
            wrapped."$name"(*args)
        }
        else {
            throw new MissingMethodException(name, Wrapper, args)
        }
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        if(wrapped.hasProperty(name)) {
            wrapped."$name"
        }
        else {
            throw new MissingPropertyException(name, Wrapper)
        }
    }

    String toString() {
        "Wrapper(${wrapped.toString()})"
    }
}

Wrapper<String> str = new Wrapper('tim')
assert str.length() == 3
assert str.bytes == [116, 105, 109]
```

Comment: Really nice piece of code! What You need `@TupleContructor`? To cover *inherited* constructors?

Comment: Saved my typing a constructor that accepts `T` ;-) #lazy

Comment: What OP is looking for is this. `Wrapper<List> list = new Wrapper([1, 2, 3]); assert [1, 2, 3] == list.collect()`. Ability to delegate to methods provided in `DefaultGroovyMethods`.